# Using Meteor Without a Meteor Database

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I am new to the Meteor framework.  I have found a lot of great info for modeling applications that use the database for primary functionality.

Does it make sense to use Meteor for a project with no persistent local database needs (aside from maybe managing user accounts)?

For example let's say I want to make an app that allows people to enter a query.  My app would then query some particular remote DB asynchronously via its API and then update the page with whatever results were relevant.  I don't own this DB, I'm just reading from it.

Does Meteor have a part to play here?  If so how do you integrate arbitrary asynch events with the Meteor page updating system that normally works automatically when MongoDB changes are made?

Anyone know of an example of this sort of thing?  Thanks!

Comment: Look into [Meteor Streams](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/) and read the [Deps section](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps) of the Meteor docs. Even without Meteor Streams, you could use Deps to develop an AJAX-based reactive data source on the client that implements the 3rd party API you're working with, assuming you don't need to use a private API key.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Deps`, you can achieve a sort of bridge between the synchronous rendering style of Meteor and asynchronous data sources. Here's an example implementation:

https://gist.github.com/matb33/8365342